# Remove strings from string A that are in array B

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have array A and Array B , I want to get as result A\B (to get only the strings that in A but not in B).

Of course I can do two `for` loops and do it , but is there some more nice way to do so ?

Thanks for help , i use .net3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var difference = A.Except(B);
```

This uses a HashSet and will be substantially faster than nested `for` loops for large sets.